# App is not getting started after migrating from Delphi 10.3.1 to Delphi 11

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

I have developed android application using Delphi 10.3.1 and after migrating to Delphi 11, the Android application is not getting started. Android app is getting crashed. I tried to run in Debug mode and getting the error - Thread process stopped.

Please help me to identify and fix the issue.

Comment: The ARC memory model was removed in Delphi 10.4. Have you checked your code for leaks etc. ?

Comment: Make sure you have reset java libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I encounter this problem and after a lot of struggling could run my App.
Consider my experiences.

- Delphi 11 also need permission added to your code.
- Delphi 11 not support android below 6.(At least as far as I researched)
- Some of component need rebuild on Delphi 11.(for example LocationSensor);
- This problem may be related to AndroidManifest.template.xml of your project. Rename or delete it and lets to Delphi 11 for create it again
- ...
  after that if you can't solve your problem, disable(dim) routines on startup App and find target routine caused problem.

Comment: Permission was already available and could you please explain hoe to dim routine on start up.

Comment: 1: on project .dpr dim all lines that you add to it. If your project run perfectly you can find lines that rise error, and If your project rise error  again, go to next step; 2: dim all of the create form lines except startup form  (e.g.   Application.CreateForm(Tf..., f..) and run it again, if error yet exist, proceed to next step, and if find wich lines couse error, proceed to next step by that form. 3: may be you added codes to Oncreate of that form and find object or codes that rise error and  by remove object of dim codes one by one you can find target object or line.

Comment: 4: reason of some error may be OnFormShow that you added to project and by dim that routines also help to find it.

Comment: This problem may be related to AndroidManifest.template.xml of your project. Rename or delete it and lets to Delphi 11 for create it again.

Comment: Deleting the old AndroidManifest.template.xml file works. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Work2Enjoy-Enjoy2Work, If solved your problem don't forget to accept my answer.